# Fade between scenes

Tags: c#, unity

So I have googled how to do this already but all the answers were for older versions of unity and use things that are not applicable anymore.

I am trying to do is fade the screen to white when the player wins, followed by a change to another level that will have a video playing.

How do I do this in Unity 5 (preferably in C#)?

Comment: you could have an image the same size or larger than your viewport that is centred and pure white. Start off with this image as fully transparent and then lerp the transparency so it displays the blank white image. Once the lerp has finished, load your next scene.

Comment: what would the could to change the transparency look like

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html    http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html    I'm on my phone so I can't post it, but read the links... They'll give you an idea of what to write. Obviously a transparent colour (white) is new Color (1, 1, 1, 0); //(R,G,B,A)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HwZQt94uHQ

Answer (score 3):

You can use the UI Canvas. Add a panel to the canvas and set the color to your preference. After you get that set up you could animate that panel to do anything from changing colors to custom sliding effects ect...

To implement something like this you would want

```
      Animator anim; 
     //in Awake()
      anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();

     // Tell the animator that the player Won.
      anim.SetTrigger ("Win");
     //then after the Win animation is finished trigger a Application.LoadLevel("yournextscene");
```